# Cannot implicitly convert type bool to System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: c#

Why this code work

```
public static List<int> RemoveSmallest(List<int> numbers)   
{
    numbers.Remove(numbers.Min());
    return numbers;
}
```

instead of this. What the reason?

```
public static List<int> RemoveSmallest1(List<int> numbers)
{
    return numbers.Remove(numbers.Min());
}
```

Comment: Well the type of `numbers` is `List<int>`, so that's fine to return from a method returning `List<int>`. The return type of the `Remove` method is `bool` though... so you can't return that value from as the return value of `RemoveSmallest1`.

Comment: Remove returns `true` if a value was removed, else `false`. It does _not_ return the whole list.The documentation is a great place to look for such things, f.e. here: [List<T>.Remove()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Would it help if I said this will not work either: `List<T> result = numbers.Remove(numbers.Min());`

Answer (score 6):

List.Remove() returns true or false, depending on whether it was successful, not a List.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

`List<T>.Remove()` returns true if *item* is successfully removed; otherwise, false. This method also returns false if item was not found in the `List<T>`.

In the method `List<int> RemoveSmallest(List<int> numbers)`, *return* type is `List<int>` not a *bool*, that is why 2nd approach gives an error.

If result is assigned to a variable like below:

```
var result = numbers.Remove(numbers.Min());
```

You can see `result` type as well:

[image]